# on_ready and on_message event is never triggered?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My idea is a class that handles all incoming and outgoing messages to a discord server. So that later on I can use this in tandem with different IRC type channel to synchronize them.

But first I wanted to develop this class, however I cannot make it to respond to a message. I intend to use web hooks, which is why I'm using the rewrite library.

This is how my class looks and is used, but I cannot make it see a message on discord and just type `hello` in responds to that message.

```
class DiscordChat:

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = discord.Client()
        self.WEBHOOK_ID = aNumber
        self.WEBHOOK_TOKEN = "AWebHookToken"
        self.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN = "ABotToken"
        self.__webhook = Webhook.partial(self.WEBHOOK_ID, self.WEBHOOK_TOKEN,adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())

    def get_client(self):
        return self.__client
    def set_client(self,value):
        self.__client = value

    def send(self, message,username):
        self.__webhook.send("Hello World from DiscordChat: " + message, username=username)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.client.user.name)
        print(self.client.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self,message):
        print(message.content)
        await message.channel.send('Hello! ' + message.author.name  )

    def run(self):
        self.client.run(self.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)

    client = property(get_client,set_client)


class TDCRBot:
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializin main program")

    def run(self):
        print("Running program!")
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        print("hello from Main program!")
        objDiscordChat = DiscordChat()

        objDiscordChat.run()

        objDiscordChat.send("Test Message for Discord Streaming text channel","TestUser Sil3ntDragon")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TDCRBot()
    app.run()
```

I know I'm doing something wrong here I just cannot figure out what.

For instance I've seen the use of `@client.event` on many examples but when I try to use it I just get an error saying that `client` is not defined. I got a hunch that might be the problem but that would only leave me with a even bigger question how am I supposed to get `client` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `client.event` is a decorator and you know that

```
@dec
def func():
    ...
```

Is equivalent to:

```
func = dec(func)
```

And that your client is defined as an instance variable, therefore you can register the events in `__init__`. Here's a stripped down version of the working code (you can add everything else if you wish):

```
import discord

class DiscordChat:

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = discord.Client()
        self.on_ready = self.client.event(self.on_ready)
        self.on_message = self.client.event(self.on_message)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.client.user.name)
        print(self.client.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(message.content)
        await message.channel.send('Hello! ' + message.author.name)

    def run(self):
        self.client.run("Token")


class TDCRBot:
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializin main program")

    def run(self):
        print("Running program!")
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        print("hello from Main program!")
        objDiscordChat = DiscordChat()
        objDiscordChat.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TDCRBot()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Feeling a little embarrassed here.. I have done this kind of event handling in other languages why didn't I think of that here... :/ 

But thanks a lot for your quick,instructive, elaborate and yet simple answer.