# Running two discord bot tokens at the same time

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, token

I need help to make a script that lets you run more than 1 bot token, without repeating the code of the commands all times for every bots, example:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client1 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')
client2 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')

@client1.event
async def on_ready():
    await client1.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('?commands'))
    print('Connected to bot: {}'.format(client1.user.name))
    print('Bot ID: {}'.format(client1.user.id))

@client2.event
async def on_ready():
    await client2.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('?commands'))
    print('Connected to bot: {}'.format(client2.user.name))
    print('Bot ID: {}'.format(client2.user.id))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(client1.start('ODExMzI2MTU1NzM0OTA4OTQ4.YCwkXQ.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'))
loop.create_task(client2.start('ODExMzI4NTU0NTc4MDgzODcx.YCwmmQ.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'))
loop.run_forever()
```

I wanted to turn it into something like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')
token = ["ODExMzI2MTU1NzM0OTA4OTQ4.YCwkXQ.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",  "ODExMzI4NTU0NTc4MDgzODcx.YCwmmQ.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('?commands'))
    print('Connected to bot: {}'.format(client.user.name))
    print('Bot ID: {}'.format(client.user.id))

client.run(token)
```

But it says
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'list' object has no attribute 'strip', anyone can help me?

Comment: Either [avoid using the decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193740/on-ready-and-on-message-event-is-never-triggered), or abstract this out to a new module and create multiple instances of that (either in a function or as a class)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try

```
for tok in token:
  client.run(tok)
```

or

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')

bot.run('bottoken')
client.run('bottoken')
```

Comment: I tried to make it like this:

```import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')
token = ["ODExMzI4NTU0NTc4MDgzODcx.YCwmmQ.xxxxxxxxxx", "ODExMzI2MTU1NzM0OTA4OTQ4.YCwkXQ.xxxxxxxx"]

for tok in token:
  client.run(tok)```
But it runs only 1 bot

Comment: oh then idk how